# Using Linq, how can I obtain a list of column names from a GridView? From a DataTable?

Tags: .net, linq, gridview

I have a GridView(gv).  And a DataTable(dt).  I'd like to be able to use Linq to get lists of just their column names.

I know that gv.Columns is a collection of GridViewDataColumns and has a "Name" property.  I also know that dt.Columns is a collection of DataColumns and has a "ColumnName" property.

I was trying to do something like:

```
Dim gvList as List(Of String) = gv.Columns.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList()
Dim dtList as List(Of String) = dt.Columns.Select(y=>y.ColumnName).ToList()
```

but I am getting errors an error that says I need parenthesis.  Am I even heading in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: The example looks like a mixture of VB and C#. So what it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [DataGridViewColumnCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataColumnCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection(v=vs.110).aspx) classes in question are from "pre generic" times of .NET, so they don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, thus are not directly usable for LINQ query operators.

Fortunately they implement `IEnumerable`, so you can use [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) first to turn them into a `IEnumerable<T>`, like this (C# code):

```
var gvList = gv.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
var dtList = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Beautiful stuff.  Yeah it was a mix.  I've used linq a couple of times only with C# and am now having to write in VB.NET and wasn't aware of the changes till you pointed it out.  Thanks!